# How to find a distance between elements in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example, I have such array `z`:
`array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])`

How to find a distances between two successive `1`s in this array? (measured in the numbers of `0`s)

For example, in the `z` array, such distances are:

```
[1, 3, 2]
```

I have such code for it:

```
distances = []
prev_idx = 0
for idx, element in enumerate(z):
    
    if element == 1:
        distances.append(idx - prev_idx)
        prev_idx = idx

distances = np.array(distances[1:]) - 1
```

Can this opeartion be done without for-loop and maybe in more efficient way?

**UPD**

The solution in the @warped answer works fine in 1-D case.
But what if `z` will be `2D`-array like  `np.array([z, z])`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use np.where to find the ones, and then np.diff to get the distances:

```
q=np.where(z==1)
np.diff(q[0])-1
```

out:

```
array([1, 3, 2], dtype=int64)
```

#### edit:

for 2d arrays:

You can use the minimum of the manhattan distance (decremented by 1) of the positions that have ones to get the number of zeros inbetween:

```
def manhattan_distance(a, b):
    return np.abs(np.array(a) - np.array(b)).sum()

zeros_between = []

r, c = np.where(z==1)
coords = list(zip(r,c))

for i, c in enumerate(coords[:-1]):
    
    zeros_between.append(
    np.min([manhattan_distance(c, coords[j])-1 for j in range(i+1, len(coords))]))
```

Comment: in 2D case this solution is much harder to implement. consider the same solution when `new_z = np.array([z, z])`

Comment: @KenenbekArzymatov see my edit for an approach that should work in 2d

Comment: is it more efficient just to combine `1D` solution with for-loop? And what is the `coords` variable in your example?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to edi tthe coords definiton in. As for using the 1d solution multiple times: this will not work. Ones that are neighbours in 2d would be far apart when you look at the lines individually.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to use the for, you can use np.where and np.roll

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
pos = np.where(x==1)[0] #pos = array([0, 2, 6, 9])
shift = np.roll(pos,-1) # shift = array([2, 6, 9, 0])
result = ((shift-pos)-1)[:-1] 
#shift-pos = array([ 2,  4,  3, -9])
#(shif-pos)-1 = array([ 1,  3,  2, -10])
#((shif-pos)-1)[:-1] = array([ 1,  3,  2])
print(result)
```